# When i pass an Arraylist from main.activity to reciever.activity gets only arraylist last value

Tags: java, android

I have two classes main activity and reciever activity. on main activity i fill arraylist from edittext and on buttonclick i want to pass this arraylist on reciever.class but it gets only last value of Arraylist. my code is this mainactivity

```
 public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
     EditText txt;
     Button check,save;
     String ts ="new ";


public List<String> name;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_conf);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sve);

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //   tmp.name.add(txt.getText().toString());
            name = new ArrayList<String>();
            name.add(txt.getText().toString());

        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, reciever.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)name);
            intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

}
`

and a reciever.class

```
public class reciever extends AppCompatActivity {
Button rec;
String tmp="";
ArrayList<String> object;
int i=0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_reciever);
    Intent intent = getIntent();


    Bundle args = intent.getBundleExtra("BUNDLE");
    object = (ArrayList<String>) args.getSerializable("ARRAYLIST");


    rec = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrec);
    rec.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (i=0;i<object.size();i++)
            {
                tmp+=object.get(i);
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),tmp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

}
```

}

how i can pass all item of list ?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is inside your **`ClickListener`**  whenever you click the `check` `Button`   you are creating the new `ArrayList`

You need to create your `ArrayList` outside **`ClickListener`** like below code

Try this

```
 name = new ArrayList<String>();
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //   tmp.name.add(txt.getText().toString());

            name.add(txt.getText().toString());

        }
    });
```

change your code like this

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
     EditText txt;
     Button check,save;
     String ts ="new ";


public List<String> name ;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_conf);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sve);
    name = new ArrayList<String>();

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //   tmp.name.add(txt.getText().toString());

            name.add(txt.getText().toString());

        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, reciever.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)name);
            intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you are creating new object of Arraylist. 
Do something like below.

```
public class main extends AppCompatActivity {
     EditText txt;
     Button check,save;
     String ts ="new ";


public List<String> name=new ArrayList<>;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    txt= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    check = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_conf);
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sve);

    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
       //   tmp.name.add(txt.getText().toString());

            name.add(txt.getText().toString());

        }
    });

    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(main.this, reciever.class);
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putSerializable("ARRAYLIST",(Serializable)name);
            intent.putExtra("BUNDLE",args);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

} `
```

Answer (score 0):

In each invocation of the `check` on click listener you create a *new* `ArrayList` and add a single element to it. Since you re-create the list every time it will never have more than one element.

Simply create the `ArrayList` outside the listener and add to it inside the listener and it will accumulate the various entries.